# Downloading via SVN for MAC

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2010, svn

I have to download a repository via SVN by using Mac. And I have some troubles with it. I, actually, past the URL and stuff. And put my password and log in right there but it still gives some strange errors and mb some of you can help me and tell how to do deals with it.

Here is my error:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.pathomation.com:****/!/%23QA_PMA.view.2_trunk'
svn: E175009: The XML response contains invalid XML
svn: E130003: Malformed XML: no element found
```

What does it mean and how to avoid this error?

Comment: The URL your entered is the web url of your project, not the one you need for cloning. I don't know about pathomation.com, but you should be able to find the correct URL to give to svn on the `https://svn.pathomation.com:****/!/#QA_PMA.view.2_trunk` page.

Comment: why do u think that it's not correct? I just posted those stars right there to be sure that no one could use it. And, actually, it works correctly via Windows. I have troubles just with MAC.

Comment: It looked weird to me because of the #QA_PMA.view.2_trunk part which is usually only useful in webpages urls where they represent [anchors](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.html).

But if it works on Windows then you're right, the problem is elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

You use incorrect URL with the Subversion client. Read the article [KB102: Subversion client errors caused by inappropriate repository URL](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/).